How to bring app to the top of all other apps in .Net MAUI mac catalyst
I want to bring the application to the top of all other apps, but i have tried all the below codes, but none of them working as expected.
code snippet
UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0];
 if (window != null)
 {
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
 }

Another code snippet
UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
 if (window != null)
 {
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
 }

Application should brought to the top as expected

Why?  As a user I would be very annoyed if I were doing something and another app forced its way into the foreground

No, it's a requirement in case where our app does authentication using a browser, and then we have an HTTP listener to update the configure status in the app and then bring it to the front.

Here is the known issue to add Topmost feature in MAUI, Add "Topmost" shell/app feature. You may track on this issue.
